# Mapping points on non-linear scale

Tags: math, lua, scale

I have a time scale (seconds) that starts at `0` and ends at `360`.

The width of the scale can vary—but let's say it's 240 pixels wide, making each each segment 40 pixels wide

```
<--40-->
|------|------|------|------|------|------|
0      1      3     10     30    120    360
```

How can I calculate which pixel I should use to plot a point, given an arbitrary time in seconds?

Comment: But you have not described needed dependence.

Comment: You need to keep track of each ticked value on x-axis and its pixel location and then treat each interval such as [0,1] or [1,3] linear in itself to locate the pixel.

Answer (score 0):

`pixel_X = timeline_left_X + time * timeline_period / timeline_width` ?